# Rendering nextjs component based on env value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to show a maintenance message to my users based on an env value but it just isnt working.

I have a value in my `.env.local` which is;

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_SHOW_MAINTENANCE=true
```

and my page looks like so;

```
const Index = () => {
    const showMaintenance = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SHOW_MAINTENANCE

    return (
        <div>
            {showMaintenance ? (
                <div>Under Maintenance</div>
            ) : (
                <div>We are live</div>
            )}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Index
```

But its just not working at all, if the value is true or false it just shows Under Maintenance.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to write your closing div in this way `</div>`

https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-shockley-mv7l3s?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Sorry, i copied it out wrong ... It was written correct in my code

Comment: check my codesandbox link its working

Comment: I did check .. If i change the value to false, the message doesnt change

Comment: yes let me check it again

Comment: the type of showMaintence is string thats why it is not showing we are live: : :)

https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-shockley-mv7l3s?file=/src/index2.tsx:140-145